# Messenger app not recognizing microphone on new iPhone 7 Plus

Tags: microphone

New iPhone 7 Plus. Installed Messenger. Messenger says to allow access to microphone.  Go to Settings > Messenger. No option to allow microphone.  Although there is an option to allow camera.

Microphone works in other apps.

iOS is up to date. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check in privacy -> messenger